# How should I structure this execution flow in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been playing around with spark but I can't get my head around how to structure this execution flow. Pseudo code follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlSC = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = getBigDataSetFromDb()
ddf1 = sqlSC.createDataFrame(sc.broadcast(df1))

df2 = getOtherBigDataSetFromDb()
ddf2 = sqlSC.createDataFrame(sc.broadcast(df2))

datesList = sc.parallelize(aListOfDates)

def myComplicatedFunc(cobDate):
    filteredDF1 = ddf1.filter(ddf1['BusinessDate'] == cobDate)
    filteredDF2 = ddf2.filter(ddf2['BusinessDate'] == cobDate)
    #some more complicated stuff that uses filteredDF1 & filteredDF2
    return someValue

results = datesList.map(myComplicatedFunc)
```

However, what I get is something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/net/nas/SysGrid_Users/John.Richardson/Code/HistoricVars/sparkTest2.py", line 76, in <module>
    varResults = distDates.map(varFunc).collect()
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2379, in _jrdd
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2299, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 646, in dumps
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 408, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 740, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 725, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 770, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 797, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 810, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 841, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 520, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 810, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 836, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/Python/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 495, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/net/nas/uxhome/condor_ldrt-s/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o44.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I suspect that I am going about this the wrong way. I assumed that the point of using a broadcast variable was that I could use inside a closure. But perhaps I must do some sort of join instead?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what you're trying to accomplish? There's a lot that looks funky about your code, but it'd be easier to explain if we knew what you were trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to run a computation that requires large input sets of historic values that "slides" over the history of interest by having a rolling window of time. Similar to how an SQL analytic function works. I thought broadcast would be best because having to reshuffle data across the cluster to match the date of interest would be very slow indeed. In terms of size, the two big datasets are ~3.5m and ~11m rows of ~7 columns of primitives. It seems that the reason I get the error is because I am trying to do a filter operation inside a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the comment about the lack of domain context, I don't think this is what you want:

```
df2 = getOtherBigDataSetFromDb()
ddf2 = sqlSC.createDataFrame(sc.broadcast(df2))
```

You don't say what the type of `df2` is, but let's assume it's an array and not actually a `DataFrame` already (despite being named `df*`). If it's an array, what you probably want is:

```
df2 = getOtherBigDataSetFromDb()
ddf2 = sqlSC.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(df2))
```

That being said, `getOtherBigDataSetFromDb` implies it's actually, well, a big data set. So while this flow could work, if your dataset is really REALLY big, you might want to consume it in chunks. Which you could write yourself, or probably there's already a library that reads from your DB or choice. But regardless, I believe you mean `parallelize` and not `broadcast`

Comment: I guess this is the downside of Python, no variable type specifiers! :-) Anyway. df2 is a pandas dataframe. Basically, for each date, I need to get a subset of the big datasets, and then pass that into the "complicated" function.